# Jenkins shared pipeline java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having this issue with Jenkins shared pipeline. Tried with a script tag and still getting the same error. The job is running fine but adding stack trace in the log

```
 def call(def suite = "*") {
cucumber jsonReportDirectory: env.Q3_DIR, parallelTesting: true, fileIncludePattern: "**/${suite}.json", sortingMethod: 'ALPHABETICAL'

List<String> logPaths = findFiles(glob: "**/q3.log")
if (!logPaths.empty && logPaths != null) {
    log.debug("log: ${logPaths.first().path}")
    if(suite != "*")
        sh "mv ${logPaths.first().path} ${suite}_q3.log"
    archiveArtifacts "**/*q3.log"
}
echo "Pipeline running on node: ${env.NODE_NAME}"
def currentNode =jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getNode(env.NODE_NAME)
/* change node lable before restore job as invoking job is asyncronous */
echo "Changing label for Node ${currentNode.getNodeName()}"
String oldLabel = currentNode.getLabelString();
echo "Old label is ${oldLabel}"
script {
    currentNode.setLabelString("BeingRestored")
    currentNode.save()
    echo "Changed label to 'BeingRestored'"

    echo "Preparing to cleanup node: ${env.NODE_NAME}"
    //build job: "Restore-${env.NODE_NAME}", wait: false
    build job: 'Restore-VM-Node', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REQUESTED_ACTION', value: 'restore'],
                                                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'NODE_LABEL', value: "${env.NODE_NAME}"],
                                                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'LABEL_NAME', value: "${currentNode.getNodeName()}"]]
}

}
```

Error details

```
DEBUG: log: q3.log
[Pipeline] step
Archiving artifacts
[Pipeline] echo
Pipeline running on node: server-vm2
[Pipeline] echo
Changing label for Node server-vm2
[Pipeline] echo
Changed label to 'BeingRestored'
[Pipeline] echo
Preparing to cleanup node: server-vm2
[Pipeline] build (Building Restore-VM-Node)
Error when executing always post condition:
java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher
at
.....

Scheduling project: Restore-VM-Node
```

I could not able to figure out the issue with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with TreeMap, build job parameter are passed as TreeMap with non-serializable comparators. below code change working fine

```
 build job: 'Restore-VM-Node', parameters: [
                                                string( name: 'REQUESTED_ACTION', value: 'restore'),
                                                string(name: 'NODE_LABEL', value: "${env.NODE_NAME}"),
                                                string(name: 'LABEL_NAME', value: "${oldLabel}")
                                            ], wait:false
```